# Understanding Rabbitmq

Tags: server, rabbitmq, instance

I recently came across rabbitmq and after reading some of the docs I had a couple questions that would help me understand how it works.

I was looking at the [work queue model](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-swift.html), A producer queues a message in to the broker and a worker picks it up, I don't get however how a worker is implemented in a real life situation, does a worker live on a server instance or can a server instance have multiple workers. For example a producer sends a message about an image that needs resizing, will a free server instance listen to the task and preform it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to kick the tires and try it out to understand more about how the RabbitMQ model works. AMQP is a fairly big standard, so the way in which you use it can vary considerably, there's a lot of flexibility there. The model you outline is just one of many that *could* work.

A worker's job can be as simple as pulling messages from a queue and performing the work with no other communication. You can attach multiple workers to the same queue to have the work delegated to the first available worker.

If your worker blocks on processing then you'll get the first available worker. If your worker is non-blocking you'll need to be careful to rate-limit how many jobs it accepts or one worker might get greedy and starve all the others for work.

You'll need to experiment with how to do this as it varies considerably based on what RabbitMQ library you're using.